# Exceptions, and how best to retry when a connection is reset?

Tags: java, exception, connection

I have some code which connects to a URL to download a file, and then performs some processing on it. However, sometimes I am receiving the error `java.net.SocketException: Connection reset`.

I would like to retry to download the file when I receive this error, say a maximum of 3 times before giving up on it. I would like to know what would be the best way to structure this.

Does the following look ok. Does it seem acceptable to place the `try-catch` block inside of a `while` loop, or is there a better approach?

All help is much appreciated!

```
while(!connected && retries > 0) {
  retries--;
  URL downloadUrl;
  URLConnection conn;

  try {
    downloadUrl = new URL(url);
    conn = downloadUrl.openConnection();
    conn.connect();
    connected = true;
    // Perform processing on downloaded file here

  } catch (IOException e) {
    Logger.batchLog(e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been wired to think that swallowing an exception is always bad, but I think here, that's the only way to tell if the connection was indeed reset. I guess you are handling the exception according to your requirements, so that's all the matters.

But I would, however, make it so you don't swallow the last exception. If it fails three times, you'll want to rethrow that exception or fail gracefully somehow.

Comment: So would something like this be okay, or a bad way of dealing with things?
catch (IOException e) {
    Logger.batchLog(e);
    if(retries == 0) {
      throw e;
    }
  }

Comment: Yea. That should be good. Or instead of throwing, you can terminate and tell the user that the server is not available. However you handle it, you shouldn't just eat the exception like nothing happened. Which I don't think you have a problem with right now. Also, you want to ONLY catch java.net.SocketException and not all IOExceptions, as that's the only thing you know how (or want) to handle.

Answer (score 3):

This is the kind of thing that I'd rather let a bullet-proof connection pool handle for me rather than writing it myself.

Answer (score -1):

AOP and Java annotations should help. I would recommend a read-made mechanism from [jcabi-aspects](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-aspects/annotation-retryonfailure.html) (I'm a developer):

```
@RetryOnFailure(attempts = 3, delay = 5)
public String load(URL url) {
  return url.openConnection().getContent();
}
```

You may also try [`RetryFunc`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.cactoos/cactoos/0.11.5/org/cactoos/func/RetryFunc.html) from [Cactoos](http://www.cactoos.org).