# How to handle stale connections in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, database-connection

What is the best way of automatically refreshing stale connections in Mongo?

After recycling the mongod service I get this exception from my Liferay Portlets:

```
com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: can't call something : /127.0.0.1:27017/connection_test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing code that polls the connection before each `DBCollection` is requested.

```
private DBCollection safeColl(String pCollectionName, DBCollection pColl) {
    try {
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("getting safe coll count on coll: " + pColl.getName());
        }
        pColl.count();
    } catch (MongoException e) {
        if (e.getMessage().startsWith("can't call something")) {
            pColl = getCollection(pCollectionName, true);
            return pColl;
        } else {
            throw e;
        }
    }
    return pColl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have "handle the exception and retry logic" in your code. This might be of help : [Exceptions, and how best to retry when a connection is reset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198289/exceptions-and-how-best-to-retry-when-a-connection-is-reset)

Comment: That is unfortunately a lot of ugly code that would need to go into the DAO layer that I'm using.  I'm gonna hold out for a prettier solution. :)  Mongo does it's own pooling, but I'm wondering if there is an external Mongo pool that deals with stale connections?