# Does MongoDB expire connections?

Tags: mongodb

I am running into some connections going stale in my application, and I was wondering if Mongo expires connections that may exist in my connection pool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, MongoDB can timeout, especially if your driver sets timeouts. It's a good idea to look at the documentation on your driver regarding timeouts. Some people work around this by testing the connection before making a query, but your driver should handle something like this.

There was a previous discussion on this in the past:
[How to handle stale connections in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10432145/how-to-handle-stale-connections-in-mongodb)

Comment: You should also note that firewalls, load balancers and the like can also kill connections after a period of inactivity.   This is the case with azure's load balancers for example.