# MongoDB: How to solve connection timed out error?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am using `mongoosejs` to connect to `mongodb` and this is my connection options

```
const optionsMongoose = {
  poolSize: 10, 
  bufferMaxEntries: 0,
  connectTimeoutMS: 10000, 
  socketTimeoutMS: 45000,
  family: 4 
}; 

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI,optionsMongoose);
```

but after some time all the request to `MongoDB` will start getting timed out. In my DB monitoring tool, I can see that the current live connection is 10 but there is no request being made to the server currently. I am sure that I did something wrong in connection options.  Please help me to find that out?

Comment: Potential duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10432145/how-to-handle-stale-connections-in-mongodb

Comment: @Derek I think this is a different question. Mongoose should be handling problem mentioned in the question you tagged.

Comment: where do you deploy your mongoose? do you enable the port for inbound requests? if you are using localhost on some cloud, change it 0.0.0.0 . are you able to run MongoDB commands on cli?

Comment: @mehta-rohan mongoose is on aws elb and it works fine for first few requests

Comment: can you share the code?

Comment: @mehta-rohan I just call mongoose connect method. What other parts of code you want?

Comment: share  the function which interact with db

Comment: @mehta-rohan I have mongoose model and calling find on that model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the `keepAlive` and the `reconnectTries`?

```
mongoose.connect(myUri, {
  socketTimeoutMS: 45000,
  keepAlive: true,
  reconnectTries: 10
});
```

Try the above and see if it helps. We need to know if it is closing the connection or it is an issue with your `code/find` where something is going on.

on [keepAlive](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/unstable/docs/connections.html):

> For long running applications it is often prudent to enable keepAlive.
>   Without it, after some period of time you may start to see "connection
>   closed" errors for what seems like no reason. If so, after reading
>   this, you may decide to enable keepAlive:

Comment: Thank you. I just read about keepAlive and I guess you are right. I will wait till tomorrow and then I will let you know if it works as it was always going down on the second day.  I did not add keepAlive but updated my mongoose to `5.2.0` as keepAlive is by default set from this version.

Comment: Awesome let me know how it goes this is quite interesting to me as well.